# Javascript file declared in <head> does not load (WP)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have an external javascript file called fdw.js
It is declared in the  section of my html file.
You can see it here:
http://forexdailywisdom.com/square-of-nine-explained/

Open the page source and do a search for "fdw" and you will see that is is declared.

Now, open a debugger and you will see that it has not loaded.

Test:

- Scroll down to "Square of Nine Calculator"
  Type a character in the Price field. You will get an alert that says 'foo'. This demonstrates that the onkeyup function is working and has not been inhibited by WordPress.
- Type a letter (not a digit) in the Increment field. Nothing happens. This should be filtered out by the validatecharset() function.
- Click on Submit. This should generate a table of numbers, but it doesn't.

This script was loading and working fine. Suddenly it stopped. I have tried three ways of getting it into the page:

- declaring the functions in the header.php file
- declaring the external js file in header.php
- using wp_enqueue_script() -- current version

The fact that the javascript shows up in the  of the html file seems to indicate that the wp_enqueue_script function has worked. Why is the script not listed in sources in the debugger?

All other javascript files seem to load and can be seen in the debugger. Only this one is persecuted, on both Chrome and Firefox.

Mystified...

Comment: The console is clear about the problem `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Looking at the source you can see that  the syntax error  is a missing `(`.

Comment: @t.niese on line 48 of the js file `fdw.js`

Comment: @PedroEstrada I know that it is on line `48`  and the console also tells about that. I think it is not a big deal to figure that out, especially as a click on the error will show the exact line.

Comment: @t.niese i only meant the comment as an addition to yours to help the OP

Comment: Thanks guys! As usual, something so obvious that escapes the programmer's attention. You both seem to have been able to see the script in the debugger, whereas I could not. Still not sure why that happened. In any case... solved!

Comment: @PedroEstrada sure but with the `@` you trigger my attention, so I will look at it to check if I did a mistake with my comment. But the line number is just another hint for the OP not really related to my comment. ;) I don't want to blame with that, but I think it's just not necessary to trigger someones for that. Sorry if my comment might have sound a bit abrasive.

Comment: @user1753389 such error sometimes happens, e.g. the window was still in focues while you did something else. I suggest you to use jshint or similar to validate all your js files you work on. You could use tools like grunt to watch for changes in all you js files of a project and then running jshint on every change.